# Google Services - Duplicate symbols on link

Tags: ios, xcode, google-play-games, duplicate-symbol

I'm getting the google services for ios integrated in my app. For reasons outside my control I can't use cocoapods, so I'm following the manual approach outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart).

The problem is the  Play Games C++ SDK Version 2.1 (gpg.framework). When I add it, (build phases, link binary with libraries, +) and build I get a lot of duplicate symbol errors:

> duplicate symbol _AES_decrypt in:
>       ../../../../../Monkey/modules/googleservices/native/gpg-cpp-sdk/ios/gpg.framework/gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
>       ../../../../../Monkey/modules/googleservices/native/gpg-cpp-sdk/ios/gpg.framework/gpg(aes.o)
>
> . . .
>
> duplicate symbol __ZTVN4buzz10XmlBuilderE in:
>       ../../../../../Monkey/modules/googleservices/native/gpg-cpp-sdk/ios/gpg.framework/gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
>       ../../../../../Monkey/modules/googleservices/native/gpg-cpp-sdk/ios/gpg.framework/gpg(xmlbuilder.o)
>   ld: 7242 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've spent a day going over the common causes for duplicate symbols in stack overflow and nothing seems to work. Removed all google frameworks and re-added them, added the google frameworks in a different project (same issue), cleared out derived data, etc..

Any ideas on what might be causing it? Help much appreciated, thanks.

Specs:

- Xcode 7.2.1
- Deployment Target: 7.0
- Play Games C++ SDK Version 2.1

Comment: I think this is a known issue based from this [thread](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/158). "This would require a fix from our end (a new lib) which prevents the symbol clashing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best solution, but I solved it by opening up the gpg file, and removing the offending .o files that contained duplicate symbols.

Followed the instructions [here](http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries/).

The files I removed are libgpg.a-* and example_mul.o

Can't guarantee it all works, but at least it's letting me do a google services sign-in at this point.

Comment: We are encountered the same problem with gpg. Are the solution with removing .o files works? If you found better solutions, post them pleasee